# adding a slidedown / slideup jQuery feature to a user interface

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

Below you will find my js. code, that when run gives out in view the below attached image.
I am desperately trying to figure out how to implement this in interface in this manner http://jsfiddle.net/JHgvK/2/
I am basically trying to build an interface so when a user clicks anywhere on the email info  (first table - with the email in the header), the info about the history slides down / up.

Any suggestions are quite welcome! Thank you for your time! If I left out and info that would be beneficial in this matter, please don't heistate to ask.

```
if (tab == "crm") {
    content = "";
    counter = 1;
    $.each(data.response, function(i, y) {
        $("div#userBox_" + id + " div#" + tab + "File").html(content);
        content = "<table class='crmTable'><tr><th colspan='3'>" + "<a href='mailto:" + y.email.email + "'>" + y.email.email + "</a></th></tr>";
        if (y.email.valid == "1") {
            valid = "<td class='value'><span style='color: green'>Yes</span></td>";
        }
        else {
            valid = "<td class='value'><span style='color: red'>No</span></td>";
        }
        content += "<tr class='even'><td class='key'>Valid e-mail:</td><td class='value'>" + valid + "</td></tr>";

        if (y.email.reason == null) {
            reason = "<td class='value'><span style='color: green'>N/A</span></td>";
        }
        content += "<tr class='odd'><td class='key'>Reason</td><td class='value'>" + reason + "</td></tr>";
        content += "<tr class='even'><td class='key'>Confirmed at</td><td class='value'><td class='value'>" + y.email.confirmed_at + "</td></td></tr>";
        if (y.email.email.contact_email == "1") {
            contact = "<td class='value'><span style='color: green'>Yes</span></td>";
        }
        else {
            contact = "<td class='value'><span style='color: red'>No</span></td>";
        }
        content += "<tr class='odd'><td class='key'>Contact </br> e-mail</td><td class='value'>" + contact + "</td></tr>";

        if (y.email.login_email == "1") {
            login = "<td class='value'><span style='color: green'>Yes</span></td>";
        }
        else {
            login = "<td class='value'><span style='color: red'>No</span></td>";
        }
        content += "<tr class='even'><td class='key'>Users login </br> e-mail</td><td class='value'>" + login + "</td></tr>";
        content += "<tr class='odd'><td class='key'>Users Id</td><td class='value'><td class='value'>" + y.email.users_id + "</td></td></tr>";

        $.each(y.history, function(ii, z) {
            if (z.contactBrand == "B") type = "Book";
            else {
                type = "Journal"
            }
            content += "<table class='crmTable'><tr><th colspan='3'>History " + counter + "</th></tr>";
            content += "<tr class='even'><td class='key'><b>Contact Role</b></td><td class='value'><td class='value'>" + z.contactRole + "</td></td></tr>";
            content += "<tr class='odd'><td class='key'>Contact Project</td><td class='value'><td class='value'>" + z.contactProject + "</td></td></tr>";
            content += "<tr class='even'><td class='key'>Contact Brand</td><td class='value'><td class='value'>" + type + "</td></td></tr>";
            counter++
        });
    });

    $("div#userBox_" + id + " div#" + tab + "File").append(content);
    $("div#userBox_" + id + " div#" + tab + "File").append("</table>");

}
}, "json");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery ui accordion http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/
or find this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/avinapaster/JHgvK/7/

Comment: I have been looking at those examples myself...I even mentioned in the question ( same fiddle), and I still don't get it.